# return to call after jumps in assembly

Tags: assembly, call

this is probably an easy one, but I'm confused about this for some time:

Suppose I have something like

```
main:
...
call some_fun
...

some_fun:
...
jmp op
...

op:
...
ret
```

would this ret correctly return to where the call starts? if not, then how would the ret returns correctly?

Comment: It's been a long time since I did any assembly, but I think that in `some_fun`, you'd have to store a return address on the stack before jumping. I think. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If in the provided example, you want the next instruction it executes after it returns to be the instruction after **call some_fun**, then yes it will do exactly as you want provided that you clean up your stack frame before returning.

Assuming that you are using x86 assembly, here is what is going on.

1. When **call some_fun** is executed, it pushes the return address onto the stack and then changes the program counter/instruction pointer to point to **some_fun** so it continues execution there.
2. The **jmp op** instruction does not modify the stack.  It only modifies the program counter/instruction pointer.
3. The **ret** instruction pops a value off the stack and dumps it into the program counter/instruction pointer.  The value it pops off the stack is known as the return address.  It is vitally important that anything **some_fun** and **op** have pushed onto the stack be popped off before issuing **ret**.  Otherwise, you will return to the wrong return address.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it still crashes then try out

move dword[stak],esp ;at the very start

and end with

mov esp,[stak]

ret

kinda thing

gl